# mysql SELECT ... WHERE decimal is whole number

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a `DECIMAL(4,2)` column. It has values like `1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1`.

How can I retrieve values that are only whole numbers?

I am doing `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%.0';` but I am not sure if there's a better way to handle the numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = floor(field);
```